# Is it okay to store key-value in mysql in some tables while other tables are normalized tables in the usual mysql way?

Tags: mysql, nosql

Is it okay to store key-value in mysql in some tables while other tables are normalized tables in the usual mysql way?

Comment: Yes, that just depends on the approach you need to get a good design. For instance, Wordpress uses that kind of solution to have a good freedom in order to include settings, different kind of posts, pages and plugin data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure it is.  I know applications that do just that.

Typically, you might use key-value in tables that are storing data whose structure is configurable.  Like a questionnaire engine.  For data whose structure is well-defined, you would more likely use the normalized structure.